# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - How to add a splash screen to Android environment?

Tags: android, splash-screen, ibm-mobilefirst

I am facing an issue while trying to add a splash screenin Android.
Below is the code I used

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.bindBrowser(appView);
    super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath(), 5000);
}
```

I see the splash image, but then after few minutes I get a blank screen and the app crashes.

Answer (score 2):

When using Worklight, you can show splash screen in onWLInitCompleted method and leave onCreate method as default.
Below code test on Nexus 4, Andriod 4.2.2.

```
@Override
public void onWLInitCompleted(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set splash screen image
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.logo_image);
    // Set skin name to skip load skinLoader.html if you have no customized skin.
    // This will fix the splash screen flicker on some Android devices when the App first time running.
    WLUtils.writeWLPref(getContext(), "wlSkinName", "default");
    WLUtils.writeWLPref(getContext(), "exitOnSkinLoader", "true");
    // show splash screen 3 seconds
    super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath(), 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know will it help you or not but just try to use this code...

```
setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            Intent menu = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(menu);
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

I do what you do in `onCreate`, but load the URL like this:

```
public void onWLInitCompleted(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath(), 5000);
}
```

Works for me (testing on Nexus 7, Android 4.2.2).

Comment: I tried this ,for the first time I run the application in android it shows splash screen and then it shows html page without Jquery components/styles applied.Later I get a blank black page and then the actual html page with expected results(with all the jquery components/styles applied)...:((But then launching the app for the second time works fine