# Splash screen using IBM Worklight for android shows blank screen at the start

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have used Dojo 1.8 and worklight 5.0.5x for android application development.the problem i face is when i launch the application for the first time on an android device it shows blank screen for sometime and then shows the splachscreen.this issue does not occured when the application is launched later on..
It seems initially in IBM Worklight all the data files are copied into application cache (data/data folder in android)at startup.

Is there any way by which i can go an avoid the blank screen at the startup and add the splash screen?

I have also added code for splashscreen in my java file.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

See this question for way to make it slightly better, as well as an explanation: [Worklight Android Splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293312/worklight-android-splash)

That said, there is currently no good way to make a viable Splash image support in Worklight with the Android environment. This, however, will be better in a future version.